# Text equivalents for icons that using css background-image property

Tags: html, web-standards

If the element is not rendered successfully, the text equivalent will be displayed.

For the `<img>` tags, we could use ALT attributes to represent the text equivalents. But things get complicated when the image is rendered as `<span>` + background-image css property. Since ALT attribute is only meaningful for `<img>`, it couldn't be used here.

What should I do to create text equivalent for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `title` attribute.

See [this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/a/aa101005.htm) and [this](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/attrs.html) for details.

```
<span title="my text" class="anImageClass"></span>
```

Comment: They are different: TITLE is for the tooltip and ALT is for the alternate text when the element cannot be rendered normally.

Comment: @Chris - very right. But `ALT` only exists on _images_. You should only use CSS images if they are _decorative_, not if they are to be a functional part of the page. http://www.accessifyforum.com/viewtopic.php?p=14211

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think it's impossible to solve my problem unless the page design is changed. Could you edit the answer above so that I can accept it?